# Overhead of memory allocator

Tags: c++11

I've been creating a temporary object stack- mainly for the use of heap-based STL structures which only actually have temporary lifetimes, but any other temporary dynamically sized allocation too. The one stack performs all types- storing in an unrolled linked list.

I've come a cropper with alignment. I can get the alignment with `std::alignment_of<T>`, but this isn't really great, because I need the alignment of the *next* type I want to allocate. Right now, I've just arbitrarily sized each object at a multiple of 16, which as far as I know, is the maximal alignment for any x86 or x64 type. But now, I'm having two pointers of memory overhead per object, as well as the cost of allocating them in my vector, plus the cost of making every size round up to a multiple of 16.

On the plus side, construction and destruction is fast and reliable.

How does this compare to regular operator new/delete? And, what kind of test suites can I run? I'm pretty pleased with my current progress and don't want to find out later that it's bugged in some nasty subtle fashion, so any advice on testing the operations would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't really answer your question, but Boost has just recently added a [memory pool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/pool/doc/index.html) library in the most recent version.

It may not be exactly what you want, but there is a thorough [treatment of alignment](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/pool/doc/implementation/alignment.html) which might spark an idea? If the docs are not enough, there is always the source code.